# Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Hangs at Waiting For Debugger

Tags: android, android-studio, android-debug

Since i have updated to Android Studio Bumblebee 2020.1.1 Patch 2, i am not able to debug my applications because it stuck at Loaded Module.

[image]

and it is not running my application on debug mode, before updating to 2021.1.1 my debugger was working just fine

it is happening to all my devices include my tablet and emulators as well

Comment: Is this issue getting solved? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @CarterChen You should clear debug cache

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the cache failure!
First if application is running or debugging on Emulator, stop it.
Then delete folder ".lldb" in path below:
C:\Users{your_username}
and after run debug again.